# SQLite exception near ") "

Tags: java, sql

I am getting error like "SQLite exception near ") ":syntax error (code 1)

here is my create table command

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "attendance.db";
 private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
 private static final String COMMA_SEP = " ,";
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +
     TableElement.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
     TableElement.ID_COLUM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
     TableElement.IMAGE_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.NAME_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.GARDIAN_NAME_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.CONTRACT_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.PRESENT_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.ABSENT_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.LATE_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
     TableElement.CHECKED_BUTTON_COLUM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + 
     " )";
```

Comment: You have `COMMA_SEP` right before it, meaning you'll have `,)`, which is invalid. Remove the last `COMMA_SEP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the last `COMMA_SEP`.

When in doubt, print the SQL query out and these syntax errors become more visible. In this instance, the `)` in the error message suggests the error is close to the end.

Other thoughts:

- Some of these static variables, eg. `COMMA_SEP`, are making your code harder to read.
- You have mis-spelt COLUMN on your column name attributes.